# Javascript Notification Appears every second

Tags: javascript, wordpress, loops, header, notifications

The Page executes javascript notification (Noty Plugin) again and again (almost every second). (Platform is : Wordpress)
It happens only on post pages [post page example](http://isongs.xyz/english-pop/strawberry-avalanche-owl-city-single-mp3-m4a-itune-free-download/) except homepage [Homepage  link](http://isongs.xyz/) and other pages.
The Original Code Of Javascript notification added in header is

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="http://cdn.frkmusic.info/static/buttons.css"/>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="http://cdn.frkmusic.info/static/animate.css"/>
<script src="http://cdn.frkmusic.info/static/jquery-1.7.2.min.js"></script>

<!-- noty -->
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://cdn.frkmusic.info/static/js/noty/packaged/jquery.noty.packaged.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://cdn.frkmusic.info/static/notification_html.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">


    function generate(type, text) {

        var n = noty({
            text        : text,
            type        : type,
            dismissQueue: true,
            layout      : 'topRight',
            closeWith   : ['click'],
            theme       : 'relax',
            maxVisible  : 10,
            animation   : {
                open  : 'animated bounceInLeft',
                close : 'animated bounceOutRight',
                easing: 'swing',
                speed : 500
            }
        });
        console.log('html: ' + n.options.id);
    }

    function generateAll() {
        generate('alert', notification_html[0]);
    }

    $(document).ready(function () {

        setTimeout(function() {
            generateAll();
        }, 500);

    });

</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try clearing the timeout... not tested though :-/

```
    var timeout = null;

    function generate(type, text) {

        var n = noty({
            text        : text,
            type        : type,
            dismissQueue: true,
            layout      : 'topRight',
            closeWith   : ['click'],
            theme       : 'relax',
            maxVisible  : 10,
            animation   : {
                open  : 'animated bounceInLeft',
                close : 'animated bounceOutRight',
                easing: 'swing',
                speed : 500
            }
        });
        clearTimeout(timeout);
        console.log('html: ' + n.options.id);
    }

    function generateAll() {
        generate('alert', notification_html[0]);
    }

    $(document).ready(function () {

        timeout = setTimeout(function() {
            generateAll();
        }, 500);

    });
```

Comment: Still Having issue... :(

Comment: Is it the same issue?

Comment: This problem does not occur on 
Tag Pages: http://isongs.xyz/artists/selena-gomez/
Category Pages: http://isongs.xyz/albums/single-dj-mixes/
Custom Pages: http://isongs.xyz/submit-dmca-complaint/

Only happens on Post Content pages
E.g: http://isongs.xyz/english-pop/stone-cold-demi-lovato-free-m4a-itune-mp3-320kbps/